# Why was "a world" used in this sentence of Melville?

Tags: wording-choice, herman-melville, moby-dick

I cannot make much sense of "a [world](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/world#Noun)" in the following passage from [Moby-Dick](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/2701):

> There’s your law of precedents; there’s your
> utility of traditions; there’s the story of your obstinate survival of
> old beliefs never bottomed on the earth, and now not even hovering in
> the air! There’s orthodoxy!
>
> Thus, while in life the great whale’s body may have been a real terror
> to his foes, in his death his ghost becomes a powerless panic to **a**
> world.

Methinks [Melville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herman_Melville) referred to **the** existing world he knew (**the world** of "traditions", of "old beliefs", of "orthodoxy") and not to **an** imaginary word (when referring to such a non-existing world the indefinite article [is frequently used](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/198772/imagine-the-world-or-imagine-a-world)). Therefore, the definite article would make more sense to me in this sentence, like so:

> Thus, while in life the great whale’s body may have been a real terror
> to his foes, in his death his ghost becomes a powerless panic to **the**
> world.

Would such sentence be incorrect in the context of the passage in question?
Why was the indefinite article chosen by Melville?

Answer (score 2):

Since this question was moved over from English Language stack, I'll repost my answer from there, for posterity, if not vanity.

All the answers [there] so far focus on the meaning of the word "world", ignoring the contrasting context in which it was used in the original sentence. I believe "a world" puts emphasis on the difference between a narrow and a wide influence the whale has; on "his (immediate) foes" and "a (whole) world". In life, the whale only terrified his would-be attackers, while in death its ghost terrifies everyone whoever hears of its story. The "world" is thus a measure of reach, as in, "a person, a family, a country, a world".